# quickly test if xy coordinates are within a given rectangle and avoid loops?

Tags: r

I need to determine the fraction of a set of xy coordinates that lie within a given rectangle. This rectangle is defined as the area whose sides are a given distance away from the edge of coordinate system(in this case the coordinate system is bounded by roughly (-50, -20), (-50, 20), (50, 20), (50, -20). Also, I want to be able to test the outcome on rectangles of varying distances from the edge. My method is as follows:

```
  # set initial limits to the coordinate system
  lim.xleft = -50
  lim.xright = 50
  lim.ybottom = -20
  lim.ytop = 20

frac.near.edge <- function(coord.pairs, tolerance){
  # set the coordinates of the rectangle of interest
  exclude.xleft = lim.xleft + tolerance
  exclude.xright = lim.xright - tolerance
  exclude.ybottom = lim.ybottom + tolerance
  exclude.ytop = lim.ytop - tolerance
  out <- vector()
  # loop through the pairs testing whether the point is inside the rectangle or outside
  for(i in 1:nrow(coord.pairs)){
    if(coord.pairs[i, 1] > exclude.xleft & coord.pairs[i, 1] < exclude.xright &  coord.pairs[i, 2] > exclude.ybottom & coord.pairs[i, 2] < exclude.ytop){
      out[i] <- "in"
    } else {
      out[i] <- "out"
    }
  }
  # return how many points were inside the rectangle and how many were outside
  return(table(out))
}

# try it out on something much bigger!
foo <- data.fram(x = runif(100), y = runif(100))
system.time(frac.near.edge(foo,  tolerance = 5))
```

This is *very* slow for large datasets (mine contain on the order of 10^5 xy pairs). How can I speed it up? Ways around the loop?

Comment: You are currently inhabiting both Circles 1 & 2 of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Read it.

Comment: Circles 3 (Failing to Vectorize), 5 (Not Writing (enough) Functions) and 6 (Using Global Variables) surely?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, I meant 2 & 3, not 1 & 2. Is there a circle for mixing up the circles?

Comment: @joran wouldn't that be a vain diagram?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a better fit for SE Code Review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r).  I don't know if this piece of coding is helpful but you're question really isn't about programming it's more code improvement.  I also generated a better data set as yours all generate an in response.

```
foo <- data.frame(x = sample(-100:100, 100, replace=TRUE), 
    y = sample(-100:100, 100, replace=TRUE))

xleft = -50
xright = 50
ybottom = -2
ytop = 20
foo$x >= xleft & foo$x <= xright  & foo$y >= ybottom & foo$y <= ytop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
exclude.xleft = lim.xleft + tolerance
exclude.xright = lim.xright - tolerance
exclude.ybottom = lim.ybottom + tolerance
exclude.ytop = lim.ytop - tolerance
out <- c("out", "in")[1+( findInterval(coord.pairs[ , 1], c(exclude.xleft, exclude.xright))==1 &
                       findInterval(coord.pairs[ , 2], c(exclude.ybottom,   exclude.ytop))==1)]
```

Takes 0.01 sec versus 19 secords for your method on a test case of 50K:

```
coord.pairs<- cbind(rnorm(50000, 0,50), rnorm(1000,0,20)); tolerance=10
```

Comment: At what point is it quicker to sort the X coordinates (keeping the order vector) and then do two binary searches for the upper and lower breaks? Then repeat for Y coordinates, and set TRUE for points within the breaks on X and Y? Hmmmm... Or is that what findInterval does? Oh yes, it does. Nice.